# How to Programatically create add new aws-cognito users in REACT

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Is it possible to use React in order to programatically create new aws-cognito users and delete them? I know one can update with `Auth.updateUserAttributes`. Is there something similar for creating and deleting users  like e.g  `Auth.updateCreateUser` or something. If possible please include an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible with Cognito JS SDK. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/tutorial-integrating-user-pools-javascript.html

To delete the user take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminDeleteUser.html